Looking for Textual Buddhist criticisms on the concept of Atman
I am looking for some buddhist works that specifically criticize or refute the Vedantic concept of Atman. Any help would be appreciated.

The word Atman is not used in Buddhism as it is a Hindu concept. You might have better luck searching for atta, self or soul using the forum's search. It might also help to understand the definition differences in atta vs atman (universal/eternal soul). My suggestion is to put aside the Hindu knowledge of atman and simply try to understand what is Buddhist atta and anatta. Once, you have a basic foundation than you will see the conceptual difference can be quite huge; making an apple-to-apple comparison a futile exercise.

For clarification, "atta" is the Pali word, "atman" is Sanskrit. In Buddhism it's the same word with the same meaning. It's when you change the context to Vedanta that it has a different meaning. There, "atman" with a lowercase "a" is the individual self, and "Atman" with a capital "A" is sort of a universal consciousness that contains and transcends the individual.

@Dan Different context and definition, Buddhist vs Hindu. The OP latest question preposition Atman in the Vedanta context. The OP's Atman is identical to Brahman. The Buddhist atman == Brahman. As far as I know the Atman = Brahman concept did not appear in both Tibetan and Chinese Buddhism. Not differentiating this really makes me uneasy.

'Atman' is a later Upanishad and Vedanta concept, not addressed in the reported teachings of the Buddha (because 'Atman' was not a core doctrine of the early Brahmin Vedas, which existed during the Buddha's life).
The Buddha was primarily concerned about the concept of 'self' or 'atta' created by ignorance in the mind of people, which is the root of suffering. The sole purpose of the Buddha's Teaching is to end suffering (rather than to engage in philosophical debates with or to embrace outsider doctrines).
The Buddha taught the concept of 'self' is merely a thought fabrication, generated by ignorance & craving. The same would apply to 'Atman'. 'Atman' is merely a thought concept.

There is the case where an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person — who
has no regard for noble ones, is not well-versed or disciplined in
their Dhamma; who has no regard for men of integrity, is not
well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma — assumes form to be the
self. That assumption is a fabrication. Now what is the cause, what is
the origination, what is the birth, what is the coming-into-existence
of that fabrication? To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person,
touched by that which is felt born of contact with ignorance, craving
arises. That fabrication is born of that. And that fabrication is
inconstant, fabricated, dependently co-arisen. That craving... That
feeling... That contact... That ignorance is inconstant, fabricated,
dependently co-arisen.
SN 22.81

In summary, when the radiant conscious mind is free from thought, the mind will clearly discern there is no real 'self'. That radiant consciousness is only radiant consciousness. It is not a 'self'; it is not reincarnated or reborn. It is only radiant consciousness. All notions of 'self', 'rebirth', 'reincarnation', 'god', etc, are mere thought imaginings, thought concepts, thought fabrications, superstitions created by thought.

It is important to understand the mind's capacity to fabricate concepts or superstitions of 'self' or 'conceit' is underlying tendency each person is born with. These underlying tendencies are discussed in AN 7.11 and MN 64. In modern parlance, it can be said the underlying tendency to fabricate views of self is a 'survival instinct' created by nature. However, this instinct is not a real self because it is merely a thought that can fade & disappear in the mind of  people.
Degrees of 'self-creation' or 'self-belief' are described in Buddhism with terms such as 'attachment/clinging' (upadana), 'becoming/existence' (bhava), 'birth' (jati) and 'death' (marana). The Buddha taught all of these degrees of self-belief can disappear in the mind of people:

Clinging is impermanent, conditioned, dependently arisen, subject to
destruction, vanishing, fading away, and cessation.
Existence, bhikkhus, is impermanent, conditioned, dependently arisen, subject to destruction, vanishing, fading away, and cessation.
Birth, bhikkhus, is impermanent, conditioned, dependently arisen, subject to destruction, vanishing, fading away, and cessation.
Aging-and-death, bhikkhus, is impermanent, conditioned, dependently arisen, subject to destruction, vanishing, fading away, and cessation.
SN 12.20

If you want a polemic work by a well-known philosopher of Buddhism (despite is common error about the chronology of the Upanishads), you can read this lecture: Anatta and Rebirth by Buddhadāsa Bhikkhu.

+1 for pointing out Atman is a later and evolved concept.

Anatta is a central concept elucidated by Buddha. Anatta means not-self. Anatta is the absolute Truth or Reality, which permanently eternally exists, even if no human is aware if it, even if Buddhas & Buddhism are absent from the world.
Buddha says the following in AN 3.136:

“Whether or not there is the arising of Tathagatas, this property
stands—this steadfastness of the Dhamma, this orderliness of the
Dhamma: All phenomena are not-self.
“The Tathagata directly awakens to that, breaks through to that.
Directly awakening & breaking through to that, he declares it, teaches
it, describes it, sets it forth. He reveals it, explains it, & makes
it plain: All phenomena are not-self.”

An alternate translation of AN 3.136:

Monks, whether Tathāgatas arise or not, this aspect of the world
remains the same – this stable truth, this fixed truth: All things are
impersonal. A Tathāgata awakens to that and realizes that. Having
awakened to it and realized it, he announces it, teaches it, describes
it, expresses it, reveals it, explains it, and clarifies it: ‘All
things are impersonal.

Again, AN 3.136:

Whether Realized Ones arise or not, this law of nature persists, this
regularity of natural principles, this invariance of natural
principles:
Uppādā vā, bhikkhave, tathāgatānaṁ anuppādā vā tathāgatānaṁ ṭhitāva sā
dhātu dhammaṭṭhitatā dhammaniyāmatā.
all things are not-self.
Sabbe dhammā anattā.
A Realized One understands this and comprehends it,
Taṁ tathāgato abhisambujjhati abhisameti.
then he explains, teaches, asserts, establishes, clarifies, analyzes,
and reveals it:
Abhisambujjhitvā abhisametvā ācikkhati deseti paññāpeti paṭṭhapeti
vivarati vibhajati uttānīkaroti:
‘All things are not-self.’
‘sabbe dhammā anattā’ti.


There's an interesting article, "The Strange Demise of Advaita", at "Chi Ting Blog". It's not just about anatta, but I'm pretty sure it talks about it.

Anatta is a central concept elucidated by Buddha. Anatta means not Self. Anatta is a concept but not the absolute Truth, it must be understood under the context.
Buddha says the following in AN 3.136 :

Sabbe Sankhara Anicca meaning all conditioned phenomena are impermanent.
Sabbe Sankhara Dukkha meaning all conditioned phenomena are suffering.
Sabbe Dhamma Anatta meaning all phenomena are not Self.

Suppose you believe that there is Atman or Self which not born and is immortal then Buddha asks that have you seen such a self ? How do you know such a Self exists? It must exist in relation to a phenomena of body , feelings, perceptions, choices or consciousness. Once you recognise the phenomenon around which you are constructing the image of Atman then Buddha says that phenomena can not be called Self. Thus he refutes the absolute existence of Self.
